# Understanding tabs.sendMessage and Promises

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

I have read the plethora of forums and reddit links and stackoverflow QnA and non answers the question or explains it in a clear manner. I've been at this for 2-3 days now just on this async await promises bs.

I have an async popup function that calls a `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` as you can see below, it is very, very basic. I send a message, wait for a response. Viola, done.

My understanding of a callback function tells me that chrome.tabs.sendMessage **WILL** wait for a response **THEN** run the function, but what happens is the function runs anyway? and I can't make sense of it. It just runs it receives asap without waiting for the content script to finish. What's the point of a callback function then?

I've tried adding await before sending and await on the callback function and any which way possible but it does NOT work. I don't understand it. Program just runs without waiting.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087734/make-promise-wait-for-a-chrome-runtime-sendmessage/52089844) doesn't work. and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) makes no sense. Promises wait on a "complete" message and somehow that makes it wait. But tabs.message callback function also WAITS on a response but still runs anyway and doesn't wait on anything?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
    console.log('got tabs id');
    tab = await getCurrentTab();
    console.log('Active tab ' + tab.id);
    console.log('Sending Message to Content');
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"},function (ret) {
        console.log('Receiving Message from Content');
        try {
            if (!ret.incident.length) return;
            globalThis.response = ret;
            processResponse(response);
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('doing nothing, bad return data')
            window.close;
            return;
        }

    });
    return;
});
```

Comment: What does your code look like on the message listener side?

Comment: @noninertialframe it receives the message and tries to do the task I set it to do. But then popup js just immediately says error, no response.

Comment: Your code runs automatically when the popup is shown so it may occur when the content scripts didn't yet run. Show your manifest.json, show how you declare or inject content scripts. Note that when you reload the extension, the content scripts won't be automatically reinjected so your sendMessage will fail. P.S. You can debug it easily if you open devtools for the content script and for the popup, set breakpoints in both and then press F5 or Ctrl-R in the popup's devtools to reload the popup.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing two different interfaces, [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage), which says that `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` accepts an optional `responseCallback` function, and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage), which says that `tabs.sendMessage()` returns a Promise, allowing you to chain `.then()`? Either way, the time between the `DOMContentLoaded` event and your callback running will be extremely short. "asap" is an apt description.

Comment: omfg @Roamer-1888 that's actually it. That, and my confusion that async/await is different from promises and callback. they're all the same thing just in different forms jesus. Yes. I had to READ chrome's developer documentation examples and sendMessage does NOT return a promise, it's in callback form

Answer (score 2):

OP is obviously very confused.
callback, async/await, promises are the same thing just written differently. Below is the updated code using promises only, and callbacks when absolutely necessary. In this case, chrome's `tabs.sendMessage` does not return a promise like they do in Firefox. So it must use the callback form. The content_script in this case does a timeout with sendResponse and it works OK.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('got tabs id');
    let queryOptions = {active: true, currentWindow: true};
    chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions)
    .then((tabs) => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "getDOM"}, (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            // processResponse(response);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        window.close();
        return;
    });
});
```